# Drop user authenticated in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I have a web system developed with ASP.NET MVC 4.

We have a user management that allows users to edit/delete other users. 
On delete function, currently i'm doing only a `delete` on database.

So here is my `login` controller/method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
    if (_loginService == null)
        _loginService = new LoginService();

    var result = _loginService.Login(loginViewModel.User, loginViewModel.Password);
    if (!result.Error)
    {
        var userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.User);
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(result.User.Id, false);
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, result.Id, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(9999), true, userData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        var encryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedCookie) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(14) };

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = result
    };
}
```

And I treat that return on client side with some javascript. This is working fine by now.

For every Controller that user must be authenticated, I have `[Authorize]` attribute.

Lets say that I just logged in with user `ABC`. As long as `ABC` cookie is alive he can navigate fine.. the problem is when some user (lets say `ZXC`) deletes user `ABC`, he will still navigate fine until the cookie expires.

Is there a way to drop `ABC` session on IIS in the moment `ZXC` deletes him from database?
I don't know.. force a cookie expire. I just don't wanna implement a consult for each action done in navigation to check if the user is still "alive" in database.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, no. There is no way to access cookies in another session as they only exist for the lifetime of the request/response. However, you could store a static `List` of all current authenticated users and invalidate them that way.

This is a bit problematic because in the case that the App Pool recycles - all users will be 'logged out'. If this is not an issue for you (i.e. the app pool recycles at 2am and it is for a business system that does not operate at 2 am) then you can try this...

**Code provided is untested**

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.authenticate

***EDIT:***
I was not removing the cookie from the request and expiring it in the response.

**In the Global.asax**

```
private static List<string> _authenticatedUsers = new List<string>();

public static AuthenticateUser (MyApplicationUser user)
{
    if(!_authenticatedUsers.ContainsKey(user.Username))
    {
        _authenticatedUsers.Add(user.Username);
    }
}

public static DeauthenticateUser (MyApplicationUser user)
{
    if(_authenticatedUsers.ContainsKey(user.Username))
    {
        _authenticatedUsers.Remove(user.Username);
    }
}

public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
{
  if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
  {
    if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
    {
      try
      {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(
          Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

        MyApplicationUser user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ticket.UserData);

        if(user == null || !_authenticatedUsers.Any(u => u == user.Username))
        { 
            // this invalidates the user
            args.User = null;
            Request.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            myCookie.Value = "a";
            myCookie.Expires = now.AddHours(-1);

            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
            Resonpse.End();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        // Decrypt method failed.
        // this invalidates the user
        args.User = null;
        Request.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        myCookie.Value = "a";
        myCookie.Expires = now.AddHours(-1);

        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
        Resonpse.End();
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not " +
                            "supported for this application.");
  }
}
```

**In your login action**

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
    ...

    if (!result.Error)
    {
        ...
        MvcApplication.AuthenticateUser(result.User);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**In your logout action**

```
public ActionResult Logout(...)
{
    ...
    MvcApplication.DeauthenticateUser(user);
    ...
}
```

**In your delete method**

```
...
MvcApplication.DeauthenticateUser(user);
...
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I think this is an approach.. but I still wonder if there are any other options... I know that in java we can use `JMX interface` to do that... there must be someting likely in c#.

Comment: You can create your own session handlers and enumerate them - but that is pretty much what the `List<string>` is doing. Cookies don't exist server side so it is impossible to change one that is not part of the current request

Comment: There is nothing else to do? I mean there is no way to `formsauthentication.signout()` passing an `id` for example? to `signout()` a remote user?

Comment: No, because the application is not managing whether a user is signed in at the server side. The user just has a cookie that says they are signed in and the server acknowledges that. The Forms auth module only checks to see if it can decrypt the cookie, and that it has not expired. All this info is stored in the cookie and not on the server. The only way for it to ever work is if you manage the 'logged in' state server-side.